# virtual function calls and casting

Tags: c++, virtual

i receive an unexpected output from some code like this:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "A::foo()\n";
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "B::foo()\n";
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;

    a->foo();
    (static_cast< A* >( a ))->foo( );

    delete a;
}
```

the output is:

```
B::foo()
B::foo()
```

this is a very simplified example. my question is:

- why does the second call to foo( ) print "B::foo()"?

i expected it to result in "A::foo()"

```
auto ptr = static_cast< A* >( a );  
// ide :: ptr is of type A*
// a call to ptr->foo() still reults in "B::foo()";
```

thank you :)

Comment: `static_cast< A* >( a )` won't change the underlying object to an instance of `A`.

Comment: absolutely correct. but how would i call A::foo() then?
--ok, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual functions work through the object itself. Inside the `A` or `B` structures, there is some information (typically called a `vtable`) which contains the pointers to the  virtual function(s), in this case, `foo`.

This is kind of the point, that you WANT to call the function that belongs to some object that is of a different type than the actual pointer (typically a "base"-class, where you have multiple derived classes).

To force the call to `A::foo`, you would call (the rather awkward syntax of):

```
a->A::foo()
```

But generally, I'd say "you're doing it wrong" if you do that sort of thing - that isn't how you should be using virtual functions.

Comment: thank you. i just stumbled across this while preparing for a exam, it has no real usecase :)

Answer (score 1):

Main function should look like:

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new B;

    a->foo();
    a->A::foo();

    delete a;
}
```